# Why does smoke stop working after 250 frames?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've tried a lot of the videos, how to's answers in here on how to get the smoke to run past ~150 frames, nothing works, bake I tried too. using cycle render and particles, Domaine smoke cache set to ~5000 frames [image]

Comment: The cache size defaults to 250 frames. Check that

Comment: OK I got that figured out, but I don't know what I did. lol tinker until it works seems to be the rule of thumb in blender. lol

Comment: In the same place where you bake the smoke, you can change the size of the cache, which defaults to 250